# (CS:GO) My bots are broken, need help

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I was tinkering with bot options (botprofile.db) and now all my bots are spinning at 10000 rpm, unable to move. What happened?

Edit: they don't spin any more, now they look right then left then right then left or up and down (nodding and shaking their heads non-stop, they can walk now, but they don't seem to be able to shoot).

Answer (score 3):

You could try to verify the game files(It will overwrite the modified file with original one)(To do that Right Click game in Library->Properties->Local Files->Verify integrity of game files), or if that is not working reinstall the game.